# What does חיו"ש וכט"ס stand for?

Tags: hebrew, acronyms

What does this abbreviation stand for? It is part of the greeting section of a letter written in Hebrew from the late 19th century. The phrase in which it appears is:

> שפעת חיו"ש וכט"ס לכבוד הרב וכו

I am guessing something like ("חיים ושלום וכל טוב סלה").

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6309/abbreviations-before-after-names

Answer (score 6):

I think you hit the nail on the head.