# Honorific for a non-Jew

Tags: gentiles, names

My question is somewhat simple: is there an honorific for particularly righteous, deceased non-Jews? Related: is זכרונו לברכה ever used for non-Jews? I don't recall ever having seen this.

EDIT: I mean honorifics appended to the end of the name.

Comment: rotten, I've heard or seen, "of blessed memory," if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6309

Comment: To address the related question of "Zikhrono Livracha", I don't see what would be wrong with saying "Alav/Aleha HaShalom" (peace be upon him/her).

Comment: @lee there'd be nothing wrong with that as it's not even a Jewish honorific. It just happens to be Hebrew

Answer (score -2):

By looking at the source we can understand the answer. OB"M or ZT"L comes from the pasuk (Mishlei 10:7) *"The mention of a righteous man is for a blessing"* Assuming that only a Jew can achieve the level of "Tzadik" that Mishlei is refering to, it seems that the honorific would only apply to Jews. [Non Jews can achieve the level of Pious Among the Nations at most see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Righteous_gentiles#cite_note-SSMH27-4 ]

NOTE: If you are writing/speaking in a forum where the honorific is used for non-jews then I believe that it should be used for derech eretz purposes.

Comment: "Assuming that only a Jew can achieve the level of 'tzadik'" seems like a pretty big assumption.  On what do you base it?

Comment: did you read the link I added ? Non-Jews can be come "chasiedi umot haolam" but not Tzadik and even then its not clear if that is possible in this day and age according to all opinions.

Comment: @eramm Your link doesn't mention Tzaddik. As counter-examples, we know Noach was a Tzaddik (Gen 6:9), and Avraham called the righteous of Sodom "Tzaddikim" (Gen 18:23). Plus we know that Iyov and Nebuchadnezzar are called Eved Hashem, which is seemingly even higher than Tzaddik (though it might not be a linear hierarchy.)

Comment: that is the point even though the link deals with a non-jew who is performing all the mitzvot that he possibly can they are still only called "chasiedi umot haolam".

Comment: @danno I suspect he means post-Mosaic non-Jews. – Double AA♦ 19 hours ago so that explains Noach and Sodom

Comment: @eramm Sodomites were effectively post-Mosaic non-Jews.

Comment: @eramm How do you know Tzaddik is "above" chasidei ummot haolam? How do you know there isn't a category for people who do more than just all the mitzvot they can?

Comment: The term "chassid" is generally understood to be a higher level than a "tzadik", so the fact that non-Jews can become "non-Jewish chassidim" (which is what chassidei umos ha'olam means) certainly doesn't rule out the possibility that they can become non-Jewish tzaddikim.