# Is there a female equivalent of Z"l?

Tags: minhag, women

When a righteous woman passes away what is the appropriate term to use to indicate "in her blessed memory"?, i.e., is there a lady's alternative to z"l ?

Comment: Why must there be an alternative? What's wrong with Z"L for a lady? Just the Z would stand for "Zichrah" instead of "Zichro".

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6309/759

Comment: relevant https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honorifics_for_the_dead_in_Judaism - one alternative you often see is a"h *aleha hashalom* - peace upon her

Comment: And by the way Yakov welcome to Mi Yodeya. If you haven’t done so already, you should take a look at the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour). Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting. I hope you'll look around and find other Q&A of interest and stay learning with us.

Comment: @mbloch _a"h_ also works for males.

Comment: @DoubleAA yes of course, didn't mean to suggest otherwise. Somehow I think I am seeing more often zl for a man and ah for a lady but it might just be me

Comment: Why want you an alternative? If the Initials are the same, the words are not.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/34388/759

Answer (score 13):

I have seen Z"L used routinely for both men and women.

Answer (score 9):

You ask what's appropriate. I don't see why [*z"l*](/a/68991) (or ז״ל) would be inappropriate. Nonetheless, I have often seen *a"h* (or ע״ה) for a woman where the same text included *z"l* (or ז״ל) for a man.