# Is there a feminine equivalent of Zt"l?

Tags: women, language, kavod, acronyms, honors

Inspired by [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/68989/is-there-a-female-equivalent-of-zl?lq=1) question, I am wondering:

Is zt"l -- זצ“ל, zatzal = zecher tzadik livracha "May the memory of this tzaddik be a blessing" -- ever used for tzadkaniyot, righteous females? Or else is there another honorific that is used for them?

Comment: I was about to make a comment, but I see that Double AA [beat me to the punch](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/68989/is-there-a-female-equivalent-of-zl?lq=1#comment197613_68989)

Comment: ...and [Isaac Moses](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/68991/5323). And [msh210](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/68995/5323).

Comment: @Shokhet Well, fwiw, Z"L really often is used for females, whereas zt"l I'm not sure I've seen

Comment: I'm not sure I've seen it used, either, but I was never really paying attention. What makes you think that it's specifically *not* being used for women?

Comment: @Shokhet Nothing. But I wouldn't be surprised if it isn't.

Comment: @Shokhet Nu, prove that it is; that would answer my question!

Comment: Fathers and mothers have the same rules regarding honorifics https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A8%D7%9E_%D7%98

Comment: @DoubleAA Thanks. But do we ever see it?

Comment: @SAH המוציא מחבירו עליו הראיה. You're the one who asked the question, prove that it *isn't* used and we'll see.

Comment: @SAH I don't know who "we" is, but if you want to see it just pick your closest deceased female ancestor and write down their name followed by זצ"ל. Now you see it.

Comment: SAH Is it? You might find a list where deceased men and women are part of a list, and if the men have ZTL and none of the women do, then that might make your question a little better. Finding something to make your question stronger will [\*searches for good words, fails\*] make your question stronger, in my opinion. That's all I meant to say.

Comment: "Zeikher tzadiq livrakhah" and "zeikher tzedeqes livrakhah" have the same initials. Similarly "za"l" or "z"l" -- works for "zikhrono livrakhah" or "zikhronah livrakhah".

Comment: @DonielF This question explicitly acknowledges the other and asks about ztl instead of zl

Comment: @ba I agree that there is a difference between z”l and zt”l, but I don’t see anything in this question to indicate that there should be any reason to assume that one might be used for women but not the other.

Comment: @DonielF Why do you need a "reason to assume"? It's a different question. Its assumptions are irrelevant. (Even so it seems quite clear from the question that the question is based on a dichotomy between righteous males/righteous females, so there's the reason to assume.)

Comment: @ba Because unless the question distinguishes why zt”l might be different than z”l, the reasonable assumption is that they’re identical. If the OP said, as you write, that there’s a difference between righteous males and righteous females (though not sure how that’s to be reflected in a Hebrew acronym), then I’d gladly rescind my close vote - that presents reason to assume that a complete answer to the z”l question won’t necessarily address the zt”l one.

Comment: @DonielF "Is zt"l -- זצ“ל, zatzal = zecher **tzadik** livracha "May the memory of this **tzaddik** be a blessing" -- ever used for **tzadkaniyot, righteous females**?" Is this not enough?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you [search Google for `"Mrs. * ZT-L"`](https://www.google.com/webhp#q=%22Mrs.+*+ZT-L%22), you'll find many instances of this honorific used for couples, and a few for women. Here are some examples of it used for women by various Jewish news or public relations outlets:

> BaltimoreJewishLife.com regrets to inform the community of the petirah of Mrs. Chaya Bobrowsky,  zt’l, grandmother of Reb Yoni Adler.

- ["BDE: Mrs. Chaya Bobrowsky, zt’l, Wife of TA's Venerable Rebbi, Rabbi Yaakov Bobrowsky"](http://www.baltimorejewishlife.com/news/news-detail.php?SECTION_ID=1&ARTICLE_ID=72026), BaltimoreJewishLife.com, March 22, 2016

> Generation Sensation was created in honor of Rebbetzin Leah Raichik ZT”L, the first shlucha of the Rebbe in California, and Mrs. Miriam Weiss ZT”L, a pioneer of the Los Angeles frum community, who both have grandchildren and great-grandchildren enrolled in Bais Chaya Mushka.

- ["Event Honors Moms, Bubbies"](http://www.collive.com/show_news.rtx?id=35457), COLlive Community News Service, May 14, 2015

> The proceeds from the dinner, as well as the commemorative journal saluting the school and the honorees, will go directly toward the Sarah Rivkah Lander Chesed Fund, established by the Lander family. Mrs. Sarah Rivkah Lander, zt”l, was a vital partner in the historic achievements of her husband, Touro Founding President Dr. Bernard Lander, zt”l.

- ["Lander College for Women Celebrates 40th Anniversary"](https://lcw.touro.edu/news--events/press-releases/lcw-40th-dinner-7214.php), Lander College for Women News and Events, July 2, 2014

I think it's fair to conclude that while this honorific is probably used a great deal less frequently for women than it is for men, its use for women is not unheard of.

Answer (score 8):

There are several instances in rabbinic literature where the rabbinic author mentions a deceased female relative and uses the appellation "zatzal". Here are two examples:

[R. Moshe Sofer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_Sofer) refers to his wife with the appellation "zatzal" in a letter printed in Likutei Teshuvot Chatam Sofer (michtavim siman 9):

> ומפני זה גם אנכי לא בקשתי ממנו זצ"ל לעולם לבקש רחמים על אשתי הראשונה זצ"ל מטעם הנ"ל
>
> And because of this, I too did not ever request of him to request mercy for my first wife zatzal, for the aforementioned reason.

Here is an image of the text:

[image: Image of page from Likutei Teshuvot Chatam Sofer]

[R. Moshe Sternbuch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moishe_Sternbuch) refers to his mother with the appellation "zatzal” in a responsum in Teshuvot V'Hanhagot ([3:377](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49820&st=&pgnum=442)):

> ועובדא דכירנא אצל אמי זצ"ל שנשארה אלמנה עם תשעה ילדים קטנים ובכתה בלי הפוגות ונתעלפה כמה פעמים לאחר ג' ימים בא לה אביה זקני הגרש"ז פינס זצ"ל ואמר לה שאסור לה לבכות לאחר ג' ימים ושאלה אותו אם זהו הלכה והשיב לה כן זהו הלכה מפורשת בש"ע ומאז לא בכתה עוד
>
> I remember an incident with my mother zatzal who was left a widow with nine young children and she cried non-stop and fainted several times. After three days, her father — my grandfather R. S.Z. Pines zatzal — came to her and told her that it is forbidden to cry after three days. She asked him if this is a law, and he responded that it is an explicit law in *Shulchan Aruch*. From that point on she did not cry anymore.

Here is an image of the text:

[image: Image of page of Teshuvot V'Hanhagot]

Answer (score 5):

Following @ Isaac Moses, I searched for Rebbetzen * zt-l and found:

[Rebbetzin Kanievsky ZTL](http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/coffeeroom/topic/rav-lichtensteins-centrist-orthodoxy-by-gaw) in the yeshivaworld.com

[Rebbetzin Bluma ZTL](http://matzav.com/rabbi-pesach-paul-z-levovitz-zl/) in matzav.com

[Rebbetzin Vichna Kaplan ztl](http://www.linkapedia-judaism.com/digest/the-yeshiva-world-bde-frum-jewish-news/37190442/baefbf786665f96af60c641c9f539775) in linkapeida-judaism.com

[Rebbetzin Batsheva Esther Kanievsky, zt”l](http://tznius.tips/the-batsheva-jabot-a-tribute-to-rebbetzin-batsheva-esther-kanievsky-ztl.html) in tznius.tips …

[Rebbetzin Chana Weinberg, zt'l](http://mekorhabracha.org/2012/01/25/rebbetzin-weinberg-ztl.html) in mekorhabracha.org

It is clear that zt"l is used for women.

Answer (score 4):

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honorifics_for_the_dead_in_Judaism), Zt"l is used for men as well as women.

If I recall correctly, when Rebetzin Kamenetzki, wife of Rav Binyamin Kamenetzki died, about 4 months ago, many of the local articles and newspapers referred to her using Zt"l. Perhaps, a Chaba"d-nick can verify if this term is used regarding Rebbetzin Chaya Schneerson.

Comment: @ezra Do you know?? ^^^

Comment: Hi I just saw this comment now XD Almost an entire year later... To my knowledge the honorific is not used in connection with the Rebbetzin, but it isn't used with the Rebbe either... In Lubavitch we generally do not refer to either of them as being dead, because a tzadik is still "alive" even after he is dead. Of course this might be infiltration from the Meshichists, and I'm sure you will find people who DO use zt''l after both the Rebbe and Rebbetzin...

Comment: @ezra I probably should have known better than to ask this regarding the Chaba"d Rebbe and his wife :-(. I gather that even the previous Chabba"d Rebbes don't get zt"l either?

Comment: Not in my experience.

Comment: @ezra the Frierdiker Rebbe no, but what about before him?