# Jewish headstone abbreviation

Tags: aleph-bet-letters, funeral-burial-levaya, acronyms, gravestone-inscription

What does פ"נ on a Jewish headstone stand for? I have seen it on many stones, seems to be a common occurrence.

Comment: answered here: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/6317

Answer (score 3):

פה נטמן - here is buried/interred ...

Comment: Or poh nikvar.......

Comment: @sam - FWIW, that's a *shewa nach*.