# What does this acronym mean?

Tags: names, acronyms

I have an Asher Yazar card dedicated Le'ilu'i Nishmat HaRav 'Ovadyah Yosef A"H. At the bottom of the card is the Rav's name followed by זצוקללה"ו. I've been unable to decipher the full acronym through [Googling](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%D7%96%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%9C%D7%9C%D7%94%22%D7%95&safe=active&filter=0).

The first 5 letters likely mean "זכר צדיק וקדוש לברכה"; but, I'm unable to decipher the rest.

I don't think this question is a duplicate (e.g. of [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6309/2091)) since I've identified a particular acronym without knowing its meaning (whereas the question cited above asks for common acronyms and their **known** meanings).

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6309/2091

Comment: If the community nevertheless views my question as a dupe of the above, I would appreciate guidance on how to add my acronym to the list there. I don't know the meaning of mine and that question's answer includes acronyms and there **known** meanings.

Comment: Your acronym is already on the list there. See too Kiddushin 31b

Comment: @DoubleAA The only similar acronym I see there is **זצוקללה״ה** which ends in a **ה** whereas mine ends in a **ו**.

Comment: I think this is still a duplicate per http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3509/759

Comment: @DoubleAA If it's a duplicate, can you please guide me on how to add this acronym to that question/answer given that I don't know it's meaning? My question pertains to this particular acronym, which isn't listed there.

Comment: צכר צדיק וקדוש לברכה לעולם הזה והבא??

Comment: @kouty  זכר צדיק וקדוש לברכה לה' הארץ ומלאו ? ;)

Comment: @HodofHod "ומלואה" - The word ארץ is feminine! :)

Comment: This has been incorrectly marked as a duplicate. I suggest you explain that it's not a duplicate because that question specifies common abbreviations, and yours is not a common abbreviation. You may also want to point out that yours is different from the one in that answer that is very similar and therefore can't stand for the same expression.

Answer (score 0):

זכר צדיק וקדוש לברכה לחיי העולם הבא

Comment: The correct acronym is זצוקללה״ה

Comment: Please read the question carefully. If needed, I can provide a picture of the Asher Yazar card.

Comment: @Lee It's a mistake