# What does LAYT stand for?

Tags: acronyms, social-convention

I received a letter from a rabbi, in his capacity of leading a Jewish institution, that opened with

> Dear _____, LAYT

I assume, given the context, that "LAYT" is some sort of Jewish blessing or honorific. What does it mean?

Comment: Congratulations! Have an [edit](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/6317/3).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Kitzur.co.il](http://www.kizur.co.il/search_word.php?abbr=%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%99%22%D7%98) has  the entry

לאי"ט

standing for

לאורך ימים טובים

LAYT will be the transliteration into English.

Idiomatic Translation - "for a long and good life"

(I normally write LOY”T.)

Comment: In which, apparently, [transliteration has won out over transcription](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transliteration#Difference_from_transcription).