# Who was the author/compiler of the Ikkar Tosfos Yom Tov?

Tags: commentaries, mishna, authorship

I've noticed when learning Mishnayos that with the more basic layouts consist of the Mishna and the commentaries of [Rav Ovadia M'Bartenura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obadiah_ben_Abraham_Bartenura) and the *Ikkar Tosfos Yom Tov*.

It is known that [Rav Yom-Tov Lipmann Heller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yom-Tov_Lipmann_Heller) was the author of the *Tosfos Yom Tov* but did he also write/compile the *Ikkar Tosfos Yom Tov*? If he didn't, who did?

Comment: Are all of the summaries printed with the title "_Ikar Tosafos Yom Tov_" the same?

Comment: [similar](/q/99430/170)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Two editions of Mishnayot I have on hand<sup>1</sup> ascribe this commentary, the עיקר תוספות יום טוב, to R' Meshulam Katz.

[This Geni page](https://www.geni.com/people/Meshulam-Kats/6000000010280926694) attributes *Ikkar Tosafot Yom Tov* to R' Meshulam Katz, and identifies him as the Av Beit Din of Lvov, who died there in 1810.

The text in the Geni page is apparently copied<sup>2</sup> from a pedigree record included by R' Katz' great^3-grandson, [R' Yitzchak Amsel](https://www.geni.com/people/Rabbi-Yitzchak-Itzik-Amsel/6000000010281103626)<sup>3</sup>, in books that he wrote or edited, including [*Kitzur Darchei Teshuva*](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41549&st=&pgnum=10&hilite=). Here is the complete text of the note there on R' Meshulam Katz:

> בן הגאון הקדוש מו״ה משולם כ״ץ זצוקל״ה, בעהמ״ח
> קיצור תוספות יום טוב על משניות ופתחי נדה, ממלא מקום
> אחיו הגה״ק המקובל הנורא המפורסם מאוד בעולם׳ מו״ה
> יצחק אייזיק כ״ץ זצוק״ל׳ בעהמ״ח ספר הנורא ברית כהונת
> עולם׳ אב״ד דק״ק קאריץ, ואח״כ נתקבל לראב״ד דקי׳ק לבוב,
> ושם מנוחת כבודו, וזה נוסח המצבה שלו בבית החיים בלבוב :
> ״נפלה עטרת ראשינו ביום א׳ דחג הסוכות, ספדה תורה כי
> נפל נזרה, נצחו אראלים את המצוקים ונשבה ארון אלקים,
> הרב הגאון מוה״ר משולם כ״ץ, בן הגאון מו״ה יואל כ״ץ׳
> מיחוסי כהונה עד אהרן הכהן, תנצב״ה״.

My translation:

> [The author's great-great grandfather was] son of the holy genius, our teacher, Rabbi Meshulam Katz, *ZTzVK"L*<sup>4</sup>, author of *Kitzur Tosafot Yom Tov* on *Mishna* and *Pitchei Nida*, who took the place of his brother (the holy genius mystic, revered and very famous, our teacher, Rabbi Yitzchak Isaac Katz, *ZTzVK"L*, author of the revered book *Berit Kehunat Olam*) as *Av Beit Din*<sup>5</sup> of the holy community of [Korets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korets) and was later accepted as the Rabbi / *Av Beit Din* of the holy community of [Lvov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lviv), which is where his honor was [laid to] rest. And this is the text of his headstone in the cemetery in Lvov:
>
> > The crown of our head fell on the first day of the festival of Sukkot. The Torah eulogized, for its crown has fallen. [The angels have triumphed](http://hebrewlog.blogspot.com/2004/07/blog-post_18.html) over the sages, and the Ark of God has settled down. The Rabbi and genius, our teacher, Rabbi Meshulam Katz, son of the genius, our teacher, Rabbi Yoel Katz, of those pedigreed to priesthood back to Aharon the Priest. *TNTzB"H*<sup>6</sup>

---

<sup>1. [Horev](http://www.chorev.co.il) Publishing House, Jerusalem, 1993; and [Shay Lamora](http://www.shaylamora.com/eng/) Publishing, Jerusalem.</sup>

<sup>2. Unfortunately without attribution, but Hebrewbooks+Google cuts through such problems.</sup>

<sup>3. Hungary and USA, 1894-1981.</sup>

<sup>4. The memory of a righteous and holy person to be a blessing.</sup>

<sup>5. President of the Court</sup>

<sup>6. [May his soul be bound in the bundle of life.](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/6317/2)</sup>

Comment: He (YTYT) cited in some places an other book that he did publish.  I don't remember,  perhaps in Yoma.

Comment: Translation corrections or improvements welcome, of course.

Comment: +1 for notation and not overloading <sup>. Interesting, that the inscription refers to this work by a different name.