# יר"ה honorific for a king in Mishnah Berurah -- a reference to a specific monarch?

Tags: history, gentiles, malchut-royalty, acronyms

In סימן דש, סקכ"ו the Mishnah Berurah says as follows:

> במקום שהמלך **יר"ה** גזר שאין שום אדם...

My edition of Mishnah Berurah the acronym is expanded as:  "יָרוּם הוֹדוֹ", which I believe means May his praise be heightened.

Is he referring to someone specific? Is this just a general honorific to give kings? I have yet to see this used. In the MB it says he's quoting רשד"ם and ריב"ל, not sure who they were or where they lived. In Shaar HaTziyun he cites this as מגן אברהם בשם הכנסת הגדולה.

A quick Google search brought me to the article of Franz Josef, the ruler of Austria in the late 19th, early 20th century. The Google result said he was referred to by Jews as הקיסר ירום הודו, but the actual article didn't have this information

Comment: FWIW, this acronym is listed in [this list](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/6317/5323) as "ירום הודו" (specifically for non-Jewish kings).

Comment: I edited your question title to make it more clear what you were asking. If you don't like what I've done, you can always [edit] it to something different. (Generally, I've found that questions with clear titles that succinctly sum up the question always do best.)

Comment: In all likelihood, he was referring to Tsar Nikolay II, as Radun' was in Russia prior to the 1917 revolutions.

Comment: Like I wrote in my question, the Mishnah Berurah is quoting other sources, so I don't know if they added the honorific (I don't have the original sources) or the MB did, so it affects who is being referred to. It could be no one in particular...