# How to write לע''נ when the father is alive

Tags: halacha, minhag, words, olam-haba-world-to-come

I understand that usually you write:
לע''נ
Joe
בן
 Shmo
ז''ל
when you dedicate something in honer of someone who passed away

But if the father is alive would you do still the same? Sources please

Comment: Why would you think you would? It's not in memory of; it's in honor of.

Comment: @DonielF I often see that when you write someone's name (who is alive) you write שי''ח

Comment: Also common are עמו״ש and שליט״א, though the latter is usually only with big Rabbis for some reason.

Comment: @DonielF but I only started to see that (עמו''ש) resently, but is when you do לע''נ an exception that you so no write anything?

Comment: @DannySchoemann I am not sure you understood my question it is (probably my fault) , when it is לע''נ someone but his father alive

Comment: @DannySchoemann or are you saying to write לע''נ name then ז''ל then בן then father's name then נ''י?

Comment: Oh. Then they write לע"נ פלוני ז"ל בן אלמוני נ"י  or לע"נ פלוני זצ"ל בן אלמוני שליט"א or הי"ד as the case may be.

Comment: @DannySchoemann you know that, that's how it is done?

Comment: And not לע"נ פלוני בן אלמוני ז"ל

Comment: That's how they have it on a Torah Etz Chaim in our shul, and that how they do it in tragic Levaya announcements. have a look at this image - http://tinyurl.com/yd93tp2e - for the longer version.

Comment: @DannySchoemann thank you (and I guess that after 120 they do not change the ending, but leave it the same)

Comment: @DannySchoemann what do you think about לע"נ פלוני ז''ל בן אלמוני שיחי' ?

Comment: I've seen (and done) לע"נ פלוני ז"ל בן יבלח"ט אלמוני שליט"א

Comment: "what do you think about לע"נ פלוני ז''ל בן אלמוני שיחי'" - fine.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/6317/603  -- see here for a list of acronyms used before and after names